# how can i add a user to a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Is there a way that I can I have in my web page a button says `"join"` which will join the user to my group ?
I don't mean it to work like the like button, I think more like the friends dialog as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/).

I'm doing it for a site that save the statics of facebook users who shared a specific link, and I want the owner of the site to be able the join those people into his group.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible.  If someone knows a way to do this : Please don't keep it to yourselves!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is not currently any Facebook API for adding [users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to a [group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/).